# Intuition behind fair vs biased result for Gambler's Ruin problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, markov-chains, random-walk

The probability of success for the Gambler's ruin problem, where gambler A starts with \$ $i$, is given by
$$P_i=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1-\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i}{1-\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^N}, & \text{p ≠ 0.5}\\
\frac{i}{N} & \text{p=0.5}
\end{cases}
$$
Plugging in values N = 100, i =  10, this results in $P_i = 0.1$ for a fair game and  $P_i = 0.00917625$ for a biased game with $p = 0.49$. Similar large differences in probability are seen across several values of $i, N$ and $p<0.5$, such as can be found [here](https://introductorystats.wordpress.com/2017/04/23/the-probability-of-breaking-the-bank/). I understand the derivation of the results here, but am having a difficult time grasping intuitively why this difference is so large. Could someone please explain, intuitively, why a slight bias can make such a big difference?

Answer (score 1):

Because the game is long, the chance the player loses in the biased case becomes very large.  The average number of plays is $Ni=1000$.  We can use the normal approximation to say the expected value is then $-10$ so the player ought to lose.  The standard deviation of the number of wins is $\sqrt{1000 \cdot 0.49 \cdot 0.51} \approx 15.8$ so winning so fast is over $6\sigma$ high.  It takes very little bias to be sure the favored party will win as long as you play enough times.  Ask the casinos, who play craps with a house edge of only $0.5\%$ and still make money.